# Thread-safe and unique execution of nested function

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a class `MyClass` whose function `A` is executed many times in parallel. Then, there is function `B` that should only be executed once. My initial setup looks simple but I doubt that it is thread-safe. How can I make it thread-safe? I'm using C++11.

```cpp
class MyClass {
    public:
        void A() {
            static bool execute_B = true;
            if (execute_B) {
                execute_B = false;
                B();
            }
        }
    private:
        void B() {
            std::cout << "only execute this once\n";
        }
};
```

Comment: The [`std::call_once`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) function might be useful for you.

Comment: You can make `execute_B` atomic_bool

Comment: Does the order of calling B matter? i.e. must it complete before all other As?

Comment: Oh, good question! Actually, it should complete before all other A's are called. Looks like I have to rethink my design if there's no easy way to ensure this.

Comment: I did not specify this from the beginning and there are already good answers. Hence, I think it would not be fair to edit my post but if someone also has an answer to this it would be a plus.

Comment: @meJustAndrew - just making `execute_B` atomic won't fix the problem.

Comment: @MrX my (1), (2) and (4) solutions will block other instances of A from executing until B is executed completely.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Could you add this information to your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a primary use-case for [`std::atomic_flag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag):

```
class MyClass {
public:
    void A() {
        if (!execute_B_.test_and_set()) {
            B();
        }
    }

private:
    void B() {
        std::cout << "only execute this once\n";
    }

    std::atomic_flag execute_B_ = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
};
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c05dad89deaae84)</kbd>

Note that any solutions involving `static` will allow only one invocation of `MyClass::B`, even across multiple `MyClass` instances, which may or may not make sense for you; assuming it *doesn't* make sense, this approach instead allows one invocation of `MyClass::B` *per* `MyClass` instance.

Comment: @Downvoter : As per SO etiquette, if you're going to downvote an answer (which should only be if it's ["*egregiously sloppy, \[a\] no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect*"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)), leave an explanation as to _why_ you're downvoting so that the answer can be improved if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your code is not thead-safe: several threads can enter inside the body of `if` statement before `execute_B` will be set to false. Also, `execute_B` is not atomic, so you can have problems with visibility of changes between threads.

There are many ways you can make it thread-safe. Note that version (1), (2) and (4) will block other thread from executing `A` past the point of `B` execution, until `B` execution is finished.

1) Already mentioned `std::call_once`:

```
void A() {
    static std::once_flag execute_B;
    std::call_once(flag1, [this](){ B(); });
}
```

2) Calling `B` as result of initializating static variable:

```
void A() {
    static bool dummy = [this](){ B(); return true; });
}
```

3) Using atomic exchange:

```
void A() {
    static std::atomic<bool> execute_B = true;
    if(execute_B.exchange(false, std::memory_order_acq_rel))
        B();
}
```

4) Protecting check with a mutex (to avoid perfomance degradation later, use double-checked locking):

```
void A() {
    static std::mutex m_;
    static std::atomic<bool> execute_B = true;
    if(execute_B.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_);
        if(execute_B.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
            B();
            execute_B.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ildjarn it is what both `call_once` and probably static initialization do under the hood. Worth mentioning if you do not have C++11 but do have mutexes and atomics from some library.

Comment: That's my point – there are already (multiple?) abstractions for it, doing it by hand looks fishy to me. Certainly _valid_, of course...

Comment: memory_order_relaxed on the inner load/store gives me a bad feeling.

Comment: @Richard mutex locking/unlocking adds a synchronization, so worst that could happen is several more threads would have to aquire lock and find out that variable is already false. You can change it to default `seq_cst` as it is rarely executed path and mutex locking cost is already high.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot : Changing it to sequential consistency wouldn't help at all with the outer load still relaxed. This is precisely why double-checked locking is silly – it's easy to get wrong, for no gain that I can perceive.

Comment: @ildjarn changed outer load and store to have acquire-release semantic. Still I don't think that few more thread stumbling on lock would kill perfomance that much.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot : That only begs the question: why bother with a lock at all? ;-]

Comment: Note that each solution are not equivalent, in particular if `B()` may throw.